# Access to My documents folder

Tags: windows-8

Can someone enlighten me as to what may have happened to cause the following:
Last night, my son tried to scan a document using a HP inkjet printer.  He didn't succeed, I think he was trying to do it via wireless but it didn't work.  He plugged in the USB cable for the printer and I think that worked for him, but he abandoned the scanning and went to do something else.
This morning I noticed a file in **MY** "my documents" folder, named "scan001.pdf".
I didn't scan any documents while I was logged on.  So how, while logged in under his account, did he manage to access MY "My documents" folder?
The timestamp of the file is during the time he was logged in and attempting to scan.
Nobody else has access to my my documents folder so how is this possible?

Comment: This question is not in the scope of the Security Stackexchange Q&A lines, i flagged this question for migration to the Superuser Stackexchange website :)

Answer (score 0):

An other user on a standalone PC being able to access your document(s) could be through various reasons:

1. Your son has the same priviledges as an Administrator (access to all users fiels).
2. The documents are a shared folder/library
3. The scanned document was still in the Queue, and got printed on startup of the printer.

Number one is solved by going to account center and lowering the permissions for your sons account.

Number two is solved by checking if your documents are shared system/network wide.

Comment: Thanks. 1. His account does not have admin access, when I logon using his account, I cannot access the "my documents" folder for my account.  2. As far as I'm aware the folder isn't shared, but I'll double check.  The timestamp of the file is from last night when he actually scanned the document.  If it had been sitting in the queue and only got dumped when I logged on, the timestamp would've reflected this?

Comment: @user2669338 That last one, but it's possible it had been accidently printed on the PC, and got Q'd untill startup, things like that can happen, but nothing like this smells like a real security issue since he didn't access the my document folders directly, please edit/comment your awnsers what EXACTLY happened, other than "my son printed it", it could help find out if you have some settings wrong or not :)

Answer (score 0):

Differences between My Documents and the Documents Library
First, off, it bears explanation as to what the My Documents folder REALLY is. My Documents is actually a virtual folder, a pointer, or even a shortcut if you will that points to a location on your computer. It's fairly simple, not too complicated.

Documents Library
The Documents Library is a "folder" that can contain a number of folders, as Windows has moved to a "library" method of organization, where you can place multiple folders from multiple locations into these "libraries" where Windows will list everything in one place. My Documents, "C:\HPSannerXYZ\ScannedDocs", or "C:\mystash" can all belong to that library. Coming from the ye olde days of windows, you can imagine the shock I had learned finally how this worked.  It's important to note the difference between the two, as the file may not actually be located in your own my docs folder, but be represented in your documents library.

Security Restrictions
Administrators can access anything on the PC, and while you said that he does not have administrator-level rights on the machine, other things on the PC might. System processes have general access to the machine, and sometimes installed devices can have administrator level access and protections as well.  Printers especially can carry on their administrator level access after installation. If I install a printer for a user as an administrator, they won't be able to delete the printer (as an example). But if they installed the printer themselves, they could.

There are lots of possible reasons, (you say your son doesn't have administrator rights, but when was the last time you checked the users list, or changed your own passwords, or changed the administrator account password? Or even better disabled the default administrator account?)

Chances are it is something along those lines.

Comment: I realise "my documents" is only a virtual folder, but the scanned image is in the documents folder ie. it is in "C:\Users\fred\Documents".  He's definitely not an administrator, he is a standard user monitored by family safety.  I suppose I'll put it down to the printer not being able to output the scanned image to the PC while he was logged in, but managed to when I logged in.  It doesn't explain why the file had a timestamp of when the document was scanned and not when it was written to disk on the PC.